# command line tool on linux to convert oracle sql into db2 sql

Tags: oracle, db2, linux, migration

IBM has a [GUI based tool to convert Oracle SQL into DB2 SQL](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/SG247736/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=3-5-2.htm).

Is there a command line tool (preferably on linux) that does the same thing? The reason being, we want to do this work as part of a nightly build when no humans would be around.

Answer (score 1):

DCW does not correct all of the possible incompatibilities in the Oracle SQL and PL/SQL, except in trivial cases. Even if there were a command-line tool (though there is not), there would always be some manual tweaking so you would not be able to fully automate the process.